# how to capture the output of sql file execution in python

Tags: linux, python, postgresql, python-3.x

I want to capture the output of execution of sql file in python.

```
cur.execute(open("file.sql", "r").read())
```

if no error the file executes successfully, but i want to capture the log for later verification purpose.

Please help with the same thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psycopg2, there is a [statusmessage](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.statusmessage) field, after executing the query. Does it return what you are looking for?

Comment: statusmessge return only the the message of the last command in the file.
but i want to capture the output of entire file.